# sql query splitting a line with a particular word

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a result as

```
code     Declaration      Quantity
123      a1                11boxes Note:(Each box Contains 20nos)
123      a2                230nos Note:(Each contains 100nos)
123      a3                60nos
```

I need to display as

```
code     Declaration      Quantity
123      a1                11boxes 
123      a2                230nos 
123      a3                60nos
```

Is it possible to split the line and to display before note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the `quantity` field for the word `note` to return a result, but this answer assumes that any notes will not be prefaced by a different word.

If you want to check for the `note`, then you can use [`charindex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), similar to this:

```
select code, 
  declaration, 
  case 
    when charindex('Note', quantity) > 0
    then rtrim(left(quantity, charindex('Note', quantity)-1))
    else quantity end as Quantity
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdafa/10).

The result is:

```
| CODE | DECLARATION | QUANTITY |
---------------------------------
|  123 |          a1 |  11boxes |
|  123 |          a2 |   230nos |
|  123 |          a3 |    60nos |
```

Comment: you are great...and now this question includes my previous things too..means count of the duplicates...splitting hyphen and along with this note..can you rectify me

Comment: @Affan here is a version that incorporates your previous questions -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afd5a/16

Comment: Pls see to this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913433/sql-query-help-display-a-title-which-comes-under-same-category ...can you guide me...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CHARINDEX()` function of sql server-2008 and get the length and use 0 to length - 1 to cut the character using `SUBSTR()`

Answer (score 1):

Or if you think some quantity may not have `Note:` try;

```
select code, declaration, 
       SUBSTRING(Quantity,0,
             CASE WHEN charindex('Note:',Quantity,0)> 0 
                  THEN charindex('Note:',Quantity,0) 
             ELSE LEN(Quantity)+1 END) AS Quantity
From YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select code,declaration, case  when patindex('% %',ltrim(quantity))>0 
             then substring(ltrim(descr),0,patindex('% %',ltrim(quantity)))
             else quantity end 
      as quantity
from table_name
```

Substring from `quantity` column value is extracted till first occurence of space character. `'% %'`

`LTRIM` Removes any number of leading blanks  otherwise above query will result in incorrect result.

[`PATINDEX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)   : Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in a        specified expression ,   the pattern being the space character here.

This will work even if **"Note:"** string is not present in column value .